# how to parse XML with list of elements without parent via simpleframework

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<list xmlns="http://namespace">
    <imageList>img1</imageList>
    <imageList>img2</imageList>
    <imageList>img3</imageList>
    <imageList>img4</imageList>
    <imageList>img5</imageList>
    <imageList>img6</imageList>
</list>
```

i have xml with content like this (not real just for discribe my problem)

want to parse it via simpleframevork to  something like `List<String>`

but everything what i tryed before  throws exceptions

my class for parsing

```
@Root(strict = false)
public class List {

    @ElementList(entry = "imageList", type = String.class, empty = false)
    public ArrayList<String> images;

    public ArrayList<String> getImages() {
        return images;
    }
}
```

and i recieve exception

```
Caused by: org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList(entry=imageList, data=false, inline=false, name=, type=class java.lang.String, required=true, empty=false) on field 'images' public java.util.ArrayList ru.cian.qa.pojo.List.images for class ru.cian.qa.pojo.List at line 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parametr `inline = true` is solve my problem

working code here

```
@Root(strict = false)
public class ImagesList {

    @ElementList(entry = "imageList", inline = true)
    private List<String> images;

    public List<String> getImages() {
        return images;
    }
}
```